# How can i Pass the arguments in the button selector method in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uibutton

Now i want to pass the arguments in the button selector method, so how can i pass that arguments in the button selector method?

```
    //Button creation

    -(void) viewDidLoad
    {
         UIButton *imageOverlayBtn = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];

     imageOverlayBtn.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin, yOrigin, theSize.width, theSize.height);

            //Pass this string into selector method 
     NSString *passString = [feedArray objectForKey:@"URLString"];

     [imageOverlayBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(overlayBtnAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

       }

    // Button Action
    -(void) overlayBtnAction : (NSString *) getString
    {
          NSLog(@"The get string is %@", getString)
    }
```

So how can i pass the string to the selector method?. Please Help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your action method should be implemented with this signature:

```
-(void) overlayBtnAction : (id) sender
{
...
}
```

Where sender is the pointer to the UIButton (in general case to a UIControl) which have invoked this handler.

Your target is `self`, so you can declare a `NSString` variable being member of this class.

So in `viewDidLoad` you will have:

```
  self.passString = [feedArray objectForKey:@"URLString"];
```

And in handler just use its value:

```
-(void) overlayBtnAction : (id) sender
{
    NSString *localVar = self.passString;
}
```

Comment: @Martin Babacaev, Thanks for the Reply. I had done the same, but still i have some problem. I have written the Action URL string in the For Loop, so it executed early. So i should pass the current string into the selector method? Is it possible? For Eg: My string is - One, two, three, four, five. The last "five" value only i get it. so how can i solve this issue?

Comment: I don't get what exactly do you mean, however if there is no other solution than to somehow pass string value, you can make a very simple extension of `UIButton` - `@interface MyButton: UIButton { NSString *stringToPass} @end`. So in `viewDidLoad` you creates the button in the same way but using `MyButton` in stead. The assign string value `imageOverlayBtn.stringToPass = passString;` after that in handler you'll get it through `sender.stringToPass;`

Comment: If i get the idea with ForLoop, you want to catch current string value by pressing the button ? If so, then you will be unable to accomplish it in the same main thread. You always will get the last number.

Comment: @Martin Babacaev, Thanks for the reply, But i can't get clearly what you said. "So in viewDidLoad you creates the button in the same way but using MyButton in stead". what does mean?. Can You come stack overflow chat room, i will be explain more about my problem.

Comment: @@Martin Babacaev, How can i get the button tag values, If i get the tag values is always shown as 0. Because i have created buttons are in the vertical scroll view and buttons are created dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

If you need a string to persist between methods like this, I'd suggest putting it in your header file. That way, you can set it when you need to and access it from anywhere in the implementation. I don't think passing an argument to a UI action is good design practice.